# (Windows) GCC linker cannot find -lcheck and -lsubunit (But all headers are fine)

Tags: c, gcc, linker-errors

I am trying to compile C code that uses check.h with this command on Windows 11:

```
gcc new_test.c s21_decimal.a -lcheck -lm -lpthread -lsubunit -o new_test
```

But then i get this error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: cannot find -lcheck: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: cannot find -lsubunit: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So, GCC cannot find check and subunit, but it sure finds check.h header and all the other headers.

What is the most common way to fix this?

Can I download check and subunit (are those .lib?) manually and give these to GCC? If I can - how do I do this?

GCC version: `gcc (GCC) 11.3.0`

Comment: Header files and library files are different things, and there's really no direct connection between them. Are the libraries installed to a non-standard location? Did you need to use the `-I` (upper-case i) option to let the compiler find the header files? There's a similar option for the linker to find libraries, and it's the `-L` option which adds a directory to search for libraries.

Comment: Yes, I know how headers and compiled object work.

Comment: No, I did not need to use -I. No, I did not install libraries to any non-trivial path

Comment: Then where *are* these libraries? Where are the actual `libsubunit.a` and `libcheck.a` files located?

Comment: You sound defensive, we don't know what you don't tell us, so we have to ask.  It's not personal and we are just trying to help.